# ASP.NET identity 2.0 log in user programatically after facebook login

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, identity

I have a web app that allow users to register with Facebook.

The process is:

1. User clicks login with facebook.
2. Users is redirected to facebook login.
3. After logging in with facebook, users facebook profile is returned to my app and autopopulates the appropriate registration fields on my app.
4. User completes profile on my app and creates account on my app.
5. One of the datapoints saved in my apps userProfile table is userFacebookID.

When user returns to my app they login with facebook and the facebook profile is returned to my app where I grab the usersfacebook ID.

I check my database for the facebookID, if it exists (this is my problem) I would like to log the associated user into my site programmatically.  How do I do this with asp.net identity.  I used to use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username) to perform this, but not sure how to do it with identity 2.0.

Thanks for any help on this.